# Show something to specific number of users and skip some others

Tags: php, math, if-statement, for-loop

I am having a little problem setting something up.
Lets suppose i have this simple page:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And in my database, i have a table with a visitors counter, which is zeroed now.

What i want to do is, to show this Hello message only for some visitors, more exactly using a rule like:

> Show for 5 persons, and skip 3 persons, then show for the next 5, and skip the next 3 again...

And keep going this way.
Sorry for the dumbness but i think i could do something with multiple numbers, i'm just having problems setting up the if, foreach, etc...

Well, if someone could help me, i will be really glad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about *users* or page *requests*.

Comment: You need some kind of server-side storage (file or database) to keep the count. You also need to keep track of users using a cookie or something (to avoid showing and hiding for the same user in each refresh).

Comment: page requests i think, each page request i increment this database counter, so the first 5 times this page is loaded, show the echo, skip 3 times it's loaded, and keep going

Comment: sorry double commenting in a row here, but @Aziz it doesn't really matter the user, Jason got it correct, it's page requests not specific users.

Comment: `if ($count <= 5) show it` .... `else don't show it`, then increment the count ($count++), and reset to 1 if it's larger than 9 `if ($count >= 9) $count = 1`. Then store it back in the database.

Comment: The other way, if you don't want to ruin the page requests `$count`, is to check `if($count % 8 < 5) show it` , `else don't show it`. The `%` is the modulo operator (remainder of division). More info: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seams you start learning, so I will give you a hint in pseudo php code what you can do:

```
<?php
  $countFromDb = getCoundFromDB();
  if ($countFromDb % 8 != 0 && $countFromDb % 8 != 7 && $countFromDb % 8 != 6) {
    echo "hello";
  }
  increaseCoundFromDB();
?>
```

Than you need to use a database like [mySQL](http://www.mysql.de/) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) to store the value.

- mySQL: http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysql.php
- SQLite: http://php.net/manual/de/book.sqlite.php
- PostgreSQL: http://php.net/manual/de/book.pgsql.php

*And you should care about that if a user refreshes the page this does not count again using a cookie or storing the clients IP.*

Comment: Awesome @tbraun89, can't thank you enough... This code worked like a charm, and thanks Aziz, your code worked too. I am using MySQL today to store it, trying to start the right way, using CodeIgniter too.

Answer (score 0):

No need a foreach.

First step, set a counter $i. Each time the page is loaded increment this counter. Then :

```
$i++
If ($i < 5) {
  echo "hello";
} else if ($i > 8) {
  $i = 0;
}
```

Second step, going further... try to detect a session ID or an IP address. Then each time you detect a different session increment the counter as just above.

Hope it help you ! Tell me if you need more details.